# How do you translate this sentence?

Tags: translation

I have read an article. (ISO 15693-2 Page 1)

Somewhere in it, it mentioned that :
[image]

Now, I can't translate it.

What does this sentence mean?

1. Subcarrier is a signal that its frequency is equal to *Fs,* And this signal is used to modulate another signal that we call it carrier and has a frequency equal to *Fc*? Is this right?

**Update:**
And also what does this below sentence mean?

**vicinity integrated circuit card**

It is a card that has integrated circuit and is vicinity? or It is integrated circuit of a vicinity card?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I read Fs, Fc as labels, not values.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would you please take a look at the Update **section** too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Subcarrier is a signal that its frequency is equal to Fs, And this signal is used to modulate another signal that we call it carrier and has a frequency equal to Fc? Is this right?

Yes. That is correct.

> **vicinity integrated circuit card**
>   It is a card that has integrated circuit and is vicinity? or It is integrated circuit of a vicinity card?

In ***vicinity integrated circuit card***, "vicinity" modifies "integrated circuit card" (or "IC card", or just "card"). *Vicinity card* is used in contrast to *proximity card*. A proximity card normally has a range of 5-10 cm. **[IEC 15693](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_15693)** is a standard for such vicinity cards.

---

These following pictures should make it clear why the cards are called IC cards:

[image: A passive proximity card for door access.]

[image: A passive proximity card with the plastic casing opened to show components: antenna coil and integrated circuit *(black object bottom center)*]
<sup>(Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_card)</sup>

The lower picture shows the inside of an integrated circuit card. Two main components are clearly shown: antenna coil and integrated circuit *(black object bottom center)*.